# Showing $I_1$ is a metric, checking one property

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces

I want to verify if my proof regarding the $d(x,y) = 0 \iff x=y$ property of a metric space is correct. I have seen some other approaches to this [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/L1_Metric_on_Closed_Real_Interval_is_Metric), but I want to check if my use of the contrapositive and the subsequent reasoning is ok.

Define $I_1: C^0([0,1]) \times C^0([0,1]) \to [0, \infty) $ by
$$I_1(f,g) = \int_0^1 |f(x) - g(x)| dx$$

We claim that $I_1(f,g) = 0 \iff f=g$.

Suppose $f=g$, then $I_1(f,g) =0$, as we are integrating $0$.

Suppose $f\neq g$. Then there exists some $x \in [0,1]$ for which $f(x) \neq g(x)$ and without loss of generality suppose $f(x)>g(x)$. Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions, then $f-g$ is also continuous. In particular, $f-g$ is continuous at $x$. Choose $\varepsilon = (f-g)(x)$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta \implies |(f-g)(x) - (f-g)(y)| < \varepsilon$.

Thus, for $y \in B_\delta(x)$ we have $(f-g)(y) >0$, otherwise, our choice of $\varepsilon$ leads to a contradiction.

To be explicit, suppose that $(f-g)(y) = 0$. Then we see that $|(f-g)(x) - 0 | < \varepsilon \implies \varepsilon <\varepsilon$. Suppose that $(f-g)(y) <0$. Then $|(f-g)(x) - (f-g)(y)| > \varepsilon= (f-g)(x)$.

Now consider $z \in \overline{B_{\frac{\delta}{2}}(x)}$. We must have $(f-g)(z) > 0$ for all $z$ since $\overline{B_{\frac{\delta}{2}}(x)}\subsetneq B_\delta(x)$. Further, since $\overline{B_{\frac{\delta}{2}}(x)}$ is closed, $f-g$ attains a minimum on it by the extreme value theorem. Thus,

$$I_1(f,g) > \int_{x -\frac{\delta}{2}}^{x + \frac{\delta}{2}} |f(x) - g(x)| dx \geq \delta\cdot \min\left\{(f-g)(z) : z \in \overline{B_{\frac{\delta}{2}}(x)}\right\} >0$$

Comment: Your reasoning seems fairly sound. You may just want to add why finding a $\delta$-neighborhood on which $f-g$ is positive is significant (i.e., we know $|f-g|$ is integrable and we have established there is some lower sum $>0$).

Comment: Your final claim to have found a contradiction is a bluff but can be repaired. Look at [this correct version](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1351550/386889).

Comment: @AnneBauval I added some clarification to the contradiction, is there still some problem with it I am missing?

Comment: No more problem, but invoking the extreme value theorem is overcomplicated. The proof linked above is shorter and simpler.